# Am I doing many to many incorrectly when using fluent nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have two main entities (db tables)

1. **Project**
2. **Application**

I have a bridge tabled called **ProjectApplication** with 3 col (Id, ProjectId, ApplicationId)

A project can have many applications.
An application can below to many different project

Your basic many to many mapping

Currently this is what i have setup in my fluent nhibernate mapping files

```
 public class ProjectMap
 {
        HasMany(x => x.ProjectApplications)
      .AsBag().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Fetch.Select().BatchSize(80);
 }

 public class ApplicationMap
 {
      HasMany(x => x.ProjectsApplications)
          .AsBag().Inverse().Fetch.Select().BatchSize(50);

 }
```

Is there any downside to this as i see there is a **HasManyToMany** syntax so I am not sure if it makes a difference in terms of the Queries that are generated  or performance, etc

Please advise

Comment: I do vote for this solution. My preference. Because the "up-side" of this, is as you use it for subqueries! good decision ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler Can you explain a little bit how can i get better performance with this aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are two approaches, as you've correctly mentioned:

- explicit mapping of the pairing object, resulting in `one-to-many` and `many-to-one`
- implicit mapping without any knowledge of the underlying table using `many-to-many`

I *(my personal statement)* would avoid `many-to-many` in almost any scenario *(while in some very rare, really admin object scenario could be used)*.

Here are some of my tries, to explain that:

- [How to create NHibernate HasManyToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135770/)
- [many-to-many with extra columns nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563082/)
- [Nhibernate: How to represent Many-To-Many relationships with One-to-Many relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510748/)

To add more here, I would firstly mention, that with `many-to-many` we are loosing the pairing object from the model. Forever. So, once our customer will come and ask: please, make one of my relations **Main**, or introduce the **Sorting** - we simply cannot. The relation is as it is. No way how to extend it.

And secondly, and most likely - *very likely*: our customer will come and ask: Could you create a filter for me, selecting only `Projects` which are related to `Application` having some setting set to *true* AND ...

And that would be a bit challenging in `many-to-many` case.

The scenario with explicit pairing object brings more overhead with that third Entity. But could be converted into Subqueries

There are some examples of the `Subquery` power:

- [Query on HasMany reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528760/)
- [Is it possible to query all objects that have one or more possible children using NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298579/)

Well, that is my point of view. Not saying it is correct. But my experience shows, that with explicit pair object mapping we are ready for extensions as well as for complex queries.