# discriminator in junction table with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, junction-table, discriminator

I have a number of unrelated entities that I'd like to be able to add FileAttachment entities to.  I'm using Doctrine2 (in the context of a Symfony project).

Before I started using Doctrine, I'd make a junction table with a discriminator column, like this:

```
file_id
entity_id
entity_type
```

So far as I can tell, with Doctrine I'll require a junction table for each entity type that has FileAttachment associations. I'd prefer to avoid that if possible. I found an NHibernate solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23261022/128245). Is it possible to do something similar with Doctrine and can anybody point me at some documentation? I've read (umpty times now!) chapters [6](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#) and [7](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) of the Doctrine manual. But I'm not finding what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an abstract `FileAttachment` class and extending it for each `entity_type` i.e. `EntityOneAttachment`, `EntityTwoAttachment`, etc.

The extended classes will all refer to the same join column `entity_id` but map it to their respective entities.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="file_attachment")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"entity_one_attachment" = "EntityOneAttachment", "entity_two" = "EntityTwoAttachment"})
 */
abstract class FileAttachment
{          
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
  **/  
  protected $file;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EntityOneAttachment extends FileAttachment
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityOne", inversedBy="fileAttachments")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
  **/        
  protected $entityOne;
}

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity 
 */
class EntityTwoAttachment extends FileAttachment
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityTwo", inversedBy="fileAttachments")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
  **/        
  protected $entityTwo;  
}
```

Then map each Entity to its respective Attachment class.

```
class EntityOne
{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityOneAttachment", mappedBy="entityOne")
  **/        
  protected $fileAttachments;
}
```

Comment: this would limit an attachment to being attached to only 1 entity, correct?

Comment: @dnagirl in this example each attachment object is mapped to exactly 1 file object and 1 entity object (think of it as a link between a file & entity) but different attachment objects can link to the same file or entity objects.