# NHibernate: could not initialize a collection:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping

I am struggling with NHibernate. I have a little ASP MVC website. I managed to setup NHibernate but when I want to retrieve data I get this error:

Additional information: could not initialize a collection: [Lore.Models.DatabaseModels.Statue.Keywords#1]
[SQL: SELECT keywords0_.IdStatueKeyword as IdStatue1_1_, keywords0_.IdKeyword as IdKeyword1_, keyword1_.IdKeyword as IdKeyword4_0_, keyword1_.Name as Name4_0_, 
keyword1_.Description as Descript8_4_0_ 
FROM StatueKeyword keywords0_ left outer join Statue keyword1_ on keywords0_.IdKeyword=keyword1_.IdKeyword 
WHERE keywords0_.IdStatueKeyword=?]

Also I am not sure if I implemented the many-to-many relationship right. This is my table structure:

**Statue**

- IdStatue
- Name

**Keyword**

- IdKeyword
- Name

**StatueKeyword**

- IdStatueKeyword
- IdStatue
- IdKeyword

**Statue Class:**

```
public class Statue
{
    public Statue()
    {
        Keywords = new List<Keyword>();
    }

    public int IdStatue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

**Keyword Class**

```
public class Keyword
{
    public int IdKeyword { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Statue hbm file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Lore.Models.DatabaseModels" assembly="Lore">
<class name="Statue" table="Statue" lazy="false" >
<id name="IdStatue" column="IdStatue">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>

<property name="Name" column="Name" not-null="true" type="System.String" />

<bag name="Keywords" table="StatueKeyword" lazy="false">
  <key column="IdStatueKeyword"/>
  <many-to-many class="Keyword" column="IdKeyword"/>
</bag>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Keyword hbm file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Lore.Models.DatabaseModels" assembly="Lore">
<class name="Keyword" table="Statue" lazy="false" >

<id name="IdKeyword" column="IdKeyword">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>

<property name="Name" column="Name" not-null="true" type="System.String" />
<property name="Description" column="Description" not-null="true" type="System.String" />

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I need to make this website for a master thesis so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue should/could be in the `<key>` mapping:

```
<bag name="Keywords" table="StatueKeyword" lazy="false">
  <!-- <key> is representing column where current Statue ID should be searched 
   while the below one seems to be the ID column of the pairing table
   so instead of this
  <key column="IdStatueKeyword"/>
   use this: -->
  <key column="IdStatue"/>
  <many-to-many class="Keyword" column="IdKeyword"/>
</bag>
```

Also check these:

- [6.3. Collections of Values and Many-To-Many Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues)
- [23.2. Author/Work](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-mappings-authorwork) - documented example with `many-to-many`

Small cite:

> The foreign key from the collection table to the table of the owning class is declared using a `<key>` element.

Another tip, if you do have an ID column of the pairing table, you should try to use augmented feature:

- [6.7. Using an `<idbag>`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-idbag)

Another cite from doc about **idbag**:

> Note that the update performance of an `<idbag>` is much better than a regular `<bag>`! NHibernate can locate individual rows efficiently and update or delete them individually, just like a list, map or set.

Finally, I *(personally)* would descourage you from using `many-to-many`. My view is, that it is better to avoid it. See: [24. Best Practices](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#best-practices) *(a cite:)*

> #### Don't use exotic association mappings.
>
> Good usecases for a real many-to-many associations are rare. Most of the time you need additional information stored in the "link table". In this case, it is much better to use two one-to-many associations to an intermediate link class. In fact, we think that most associations are one-to-many and many-to-one, you should be careful when using any other association style and ask yourself if it is really neccessary.

Maybe later also check these:

- [Am I doing many to many incorrectly when using fluent nhibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015561/)
- [How to create NHibernate HasManyToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135770/)
- [many-to-many with extra columns nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563082/)
- [Nhibernate: How to represent Many-To-Many relationships with One-to-Many relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510748/)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I decided to change my relationships to one-to-many. Which is indeed the correct way to go in this case.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. Enjoy NHibernate ;)

Comment: Sorry but I also wanted to try with many-to-many relationships and I can't seem to get it working. I adjusted my xml file like you said but still get the same error. Any ideas? thx a lot!

Comment: Ok I fixed it, had a copy paste typo.