# nHibernate QueryOver Having clause with OR condition

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

How to achieve the below query in nHibernate using queryover

### Query

```
SELECT [DepartmentID]  ,COUNT(courseId)
FROM  [Course]
where [DepartmentID] >1
GROUP BY [DepartmentID]
hAVING COUNT(courseId) = 2 or  COUNT(courseId) = 3;
```

---

Table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course](
[CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Credits] [int] NOT NULL,
[DepartmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

---

C# code i tried

```
Collection<Course> courseList = new Collection<Course>();
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession("ConnectionName1"))
{
   Course courseAlias = null;
   SimpleExpression e1 = Restrictions.Ge(Projections.Count(Projections.Property(() => courseAlias.CourseID)), 2);
   SimpleExpression e2 = Restrictions.Ge(Projections.Count(Projections.Property(() => courseAlias.CourseID)), 3);
   var results2 = session.QueryOver<Course>(() => courseAlias)
                  .Where(e1||e2)
                  .SelectList(list => list
            .SelectGroup(x => x.DepartmentID).WithAlias(() => courseAlias.DepartmentID)
            .SelectCount(x => x.CourseID).WithAlias(() => courseAlias.CourseID)
             ).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Course>()).List<Course>();
}
```

Comment: Could you show us code snippet you've tried? What do you have so far? there is some inspiartion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528760/ and doc: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look like this

```
Course courseAlias = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Course>(() => courseAlias)
    .SelectList(l => l
    .SelectGroup(item => item.DepartmentID).WithAlias( () => courseAlias.DepartmentID)
    .SelectCount(item => item.StatusID).WithAlias(() => courseAlias.StatusID)
    )
    // WHERE Clause
    .Where(item => item.DepartmentID > 1)
    // HAVING Clause
    .Where( Restrictions.In(
        Projections.Count<Course>(item => item.StatusID)
        , new List<int> {2, 3})
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Course>())

var list = query
    // take skip...
    .List<Course>();
```

Comment: suppose if we have a scenario like having clause contains mixed of 'and' ,'or' condition how to handle it

Comment: Not sure if these would be possible... but in general, my answer give you some hints how to do it in common... Play with, try to experiment with `Restrictions.Or`... `Restrictions.Disjunction()`... but HAVING clause really requires some special handling, not all wil be accepted. But your requirement the answered snippet will solve ;)

Comment: I am having the similar problem. Need conditions in where and in having clause but it all appears in where result in error in sql. Tried this solution but queryover hangs it. Used like this                     .Where(WhereConjunction)
.Where(HavingConjunction) separate. Not working.

Comment: @qazifarhan I would suggest, ask question with more details, you will get your answer. If I will know, I will try to assist...

Comment: OK will post question in few minutes. My Query is very big and complex so cannot put every thing. But will try in few minutes. Thanks

Comment: @qazifarhan Well, be smart, create question which one could reproduce and give you answer. Huge anything will not work... none will touch it... be smart ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565783/nhibernate-queryover-criteria-appearing-in-where-instead-in-having-clause-err