# Nhibernate subquery with multiple columns join

Tags: c#, t-sql, nhibernate, queryover

I have database structure for Plans and PlanVersions in following relationship:

```
 +------+                  +-------------+
 | Plan |  --------------> | PlanVersion |
 +------+  1        (1..n) +-------------+
```

PlanVersion is version table tracking all version changes and it have **ActiveFromData** and **ActiveToData** columns show us when was this version active.
Plan also can have SubPlans which can change in time so PlanVersion also have **ParrentPlanId** column which tell us what was current subplan for version.

What i want is to get all changes of all SubPlans since some time and for specific Plan.
This query is what i came with:

```
DECLARE @since datetime;
set @since = '2014-08-27 12:00:00.000';

DECLARE @parrentPlan bigint;
set @parrentPlan = 1;

SELECT pv.* 
FROM [dbo].[PlanVersion] pv
INNER JOIN
    /* Query Over subselect*/
    (
       SELECT PlanId, MAX(ActiveFromDate) AS MaxActiveFromDate
       FROM [dbo].[PlanVersion] pv 
       WHERE pv.ParentPlanId=@parrentPlan
       GROUP BY PlanId
    ) groupedVersions
ON pv.ParentPlanId = groupedVersions.PlanId 
    AND pv.ActiveFromDate = groupedVersions.MaxActiveFromDate
WHERE (pv.ActiveFromDate>=@since OR pv.ActiveToDate>@since)
```

Now i want is translate that to Nhibernate QueryOver:
i have this code

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<PlanVersion>()
                    .Where(x => x.ParentPlan.Id == parrentPlanId)
                    .Select(
                         Projections.Group<PlanVersion>(e => e.ParrentPlan.Id),
                         Projections.Max<PlanVersion>(e => e.ActiveFromDate)
                    );
```

But i dont know how to write that inner join on Two columns from suquery in QueryOver.

Notes:

1. We use Nhibernate 3.3 with 4.0 in testing
2. This query will be part of polling so performance is really important for me

Comment: You can't join on a derived table with QueryOver. You must join on mapped entity associations.

Comment: Thanks for reply but thats a huge disapointment for NHibernate. I know i can do QueryOver<PlanVersion>.WithSubquery.WhereProperty<PlanVersion>(pv=>pv.ParrentPlan.Id).In(subquery) but that only works if i select IDs in subquery. Is there any solution or alternative for that in Nhibernate? They have to solve problems like this in mature ORM framework like NHibernate.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't have a lot of options in the NH world. You could always write a stored procedure and drop back into that for this particular query

Comment: If performance is your main concern - I would stick with raw sql (use a named sql-query). I never get the aversion to using the right tool for the right job...NHibernate gives tons of flexibility in this respect.

Comment: Its really a disappointment that we cannot use subquery as derived table. My boss said no to stored procs. I need to return 4 last vendors on max(transactiondate) for each product. Found no solution anywhere since a month. If you guys have any idea, plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that this has solution. We have to use a bit more complex SQL in fact. This approach I've already deeply explained here:

- [Query on HasMany reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528760/)

So, below is just a draft based on your subquery draft. What we are doing, is creating two subselects in fact (check the intended SQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537260/1679310))

```
PlanVersion planVersion = null;

// the most INNER SELECT
var maxSubquery = QueryOver.Of<PlanVersion>()
   .SelectList(l => l
    .SelectGroup(item => item.ParentPlan.Id)
    .SelectMax(item => item.ActiveFromDate)
    )
    // WHERE Clause
   .Where(item => item.ParentPlan.Id == planVersion.ParentPlan.Id)
   // HAVING Clause
   .Where(Restrictions.EqProperty(
      Projections.Max<PlanVersion>(item => item.ActiveFromDate),
      Projections.Property(() => planVersion.ActiveFromDate)
    ));

// the middle SELECT
var successSubquery = QueryOver.Of<PlanVersion>(() => planVersion )
    // the Plan ID
    .Select(pv => pv.ParentPlan.Id)
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereExists(maxSubquery)
    ;
```

having this subqueries, we can ask for plan itself:

```
// the most outer SELECT
var query = session.QueryOver<Plan>()
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereProperty(p => p.Id)
    .In(successSubquery)
    .List<Plan>();
```

There could be some minor typos, but the draft should give you clear answer how to...

Comment: Amazing to see that sir! Enjoy NHibernate, great tool ;)