# QueryOver, GroupBy and Subselect

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

how can I do this with queryover and a subquery?

```
FakturaObjektGutschrift fog = null;
int[] idS = Session.QueryOver(() => fog)
            .SelectList( list => list
                .SelectMax(() => fog.Id)
                .SelectGroup(() => fog.SammelKontierung)   
             ).List<object[]>().Select(x => (int)x[0]).ToArray();
```

And using the ids in another query

```
IQueryOver<Beleg, Beleg> sdfsd = Session.QueryOver(() => bGut)
    .AndRestrictionOn(() => fog.Id).IsIn(idS); //iDs is a list of int.
```

I would like do this with a subquery because there is a limitation on the number of parameters for a SQL query. How do I do this?

How do I write the first query, but without selecting the SelectGroup()? This is exactly where I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Group by** without projection in **QueryOver API** is currently not supported [link](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1426).

You can use **LINQ** to create the projection in a subquery:

```
 var subquery = Session.Query<FakturaObjektGutschrift>()
     .GroupBy(x => x.SammelKontierung)
     .Select(x => x.Max(y => y.Id));

 var query = Session.Query<Beleg>()
     .Where(x => subquery.Contains(x.Id));
```

If you really needs **QueryOver** to create more complex queries check this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30915886/1486443).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! My workaround: i created an additional db-view, mapped it and working with a subquery which does not contain a groupby.