# Group by with different select Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I want to do this SQL query in Nhibernate QueryOver:

```
SELECT id FROM tb_example
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY name
```

**What I tried:**

**1)** I added a `.Select` in `SelectList` trying to override the select of `SelectGroup` but no success

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Person>()
                   .SelectList(list => list
                   .Select(p => p.Id)
                   .SelectGroup(p => p.Id)
                   .SelectGroup(p => p.Name));
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Asc;
```

Generated SQL with `query`:

```
SELECT id, id, name FROM tb_example
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY name
```

**2)** Using query in results of another query. Like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM 
  (SELECT id, name FROM tb_example
  GROUP BY id, name
  ORDER BY name)
```

But I don't know how to create a query of results from another query.

```
var groupByQuery = session.QueryOver<Person>()
                       .SelectList(list => list
                       .SelectGroup(p => p.Id)
                       .SelectGroup(p => p.Name));
var query = session.QueryOver<?????>();
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding #1, unfortunately with QueryOver you _must_ `SELECT` all of the grouping columns. #2 is completely impossible, as far as I know. QueryOver can only select from mapped tables (not arbitrary table expressions like your example shows).

Comment: Also see this Q&A, might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30913037/497356

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I know is:

```
var query = session
  .QueryOver<Person>()
  .SelectList(list => list
    .SelectGroup(p => p.Id)
    .SelectGroup(p => p.Name));
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Asc;
query.List().Select(x => (int)x[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for anwsering. I can't execute the query and then use linq. With the result of this query I will use it in a .In. With a list or array, the 2100 parameters limitation will stop me. That's why I'm looking for a  NHibernate solution.

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago. Can't remember how I solved it. Need to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below example

```
  var groupByQuery =   (from p
        in this.Session.Query<Person>()
        group p by new { Id= p.Id, Name= p.Name}
        into g
        select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Soner, thanks for answering. I'm getting a compiler error in select p "The types argument cannot be inferred from the query". And I didn't find where you do the select only in p.Id, can you explain it a little?

Comment: There is a small mistake in `select`, here the syntax correct query:

      var groupByQuery =   (from p
            in this.Session.Query<Person>()
            group p by new { Id= p.Id, Name= p.Name}
            into g
            select g).ToList();